# Android Build.Manufacturer is unknown for some devices

Tags: android

In some devices, **Build.MANUFACTURER, Build.MODEL and Build.BRAND** are coming as unknown.

Can anyone help me on this.

Its very thankful for the help.

Comment: What device are you referring to? The `build.prop` file in the root of the file-system probably has that as empty or omitted. Do not rely on that field as that is an optional thing, some manufacturers are free to either fill it in or omit it entirely.

Comment: Iam getting this the DROID. May I know where can I find the build.prop.